# Why add a preceding vertical bar (|) to a union type literal in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following TypeScript code:

```
type FeatureFlagConfig = { enabled: false }
  | {
      enabled: true;
      key: string;
    };
```

Then, in VSCode upon saving it got autoformatted to:

```
type FeatureFlagConfig =
  | { enabled: false }
  | {
      enabled: true;
      key: string;
    };
```

What's interesting here is the union literal has the syntax `| a | b` instead of `a | b`. Adding the initial `|` (vertical bar) character looks like broken code but is apparently what the linter prefers. Why? Is this exclusively for formatting purposes, so that each union member goes on its own line? Also, is this valid TS? The TS spec doesn't mention it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#386-union-type-literals

Comment: "Why? Is this exclusively for formatting purposes, so that each union member goes on its own line?". Yes. It's like trailing comma in JSON or such.

Answer (score 6):

Despite not mentioning this syntax in the spec, Typescript does support it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12071

It is optional to provide a leading `|` (or `&`) character instead of just using these characters to separate options in a type union/intersection. The sole purpose is to give more flexibility in code formatting. This syntax is shared with other languages e.g. Flow, F# and was added in "TypeScript 2.1.3, Community on Nov 28, 2016".